# How can I perform group by operations on the last 3 months data (cumulatively) in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by

Hopefully you can help.

I am trying to groupby / resample based on criteria that I cannot find a solution to. I am looking to apply the quantile(0.9) function across the criteria below and group by a category.

The challenge I am facing is that there are overlaps in the ranges i.e.

Jan22 - Mar 22
Feb22 - Apr 22
Mar22 - May 22

A sample of the data is as follows:

| Dates | Category | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | A | 1 |
| 01/01/2022 | B | 2 |
| 02/01/2022 | A | 3 |
| 02/01/2022 | B | 4 |
| … |  |  |
| 01/02/2022 | A | 6 |
| 01/02/2022 | B | 7 |
| 02/02/2022 | A | 8 |
| 02/02/2022 | B | 9 |
| … |  |  |
| 01/03/2022 | A | 11 |
| 01/03/2022 | B | 12 |
| 02/03/2022 | A | 13 |
| 02/03/2022 | B | 14 |
| … |  |  |
| 01/04/2022 | A | 16 |
| 01/04/2022 | B | 17 |
| 02/04/2022 | A | 18 |
| 02/04/2022 | B | 19 |

The final output I am hoping to see is:

| Category | Jan 22 - Mar22 | Feb22 - Apr22 | Mar22 - May22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | quantile(0.9) | quantile(0.9) | quantile(0.9) |
| b | quantile(0.9) | quantile(0.9) | quantile(0.9) |

quantile(0.9) is the value returned by the function. A solution with or without the category grouping would be very much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Steven

I tried the offset aliases and could not see a solution using groupby with a custom function. Apologies if I have overlooked something fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df["Dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dates"], dayfirst=True)

ofs1 = pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=1)
ofs2 = pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin(n=2)
max_date = df["Dates"].max() + ofs1
cur1 = df["Dates"].min()
cur2 = cur1 + ofs2
ranges = []

while True:
    if cur2 > max_date:
        break
    m1, y1 = cur1.month, cur1.year
    m2, y2 = cur2.month, cur2.year
    ranges.append(
        (
            pd.to_datetime(f"1/{m1}/{y1}", dayfirst=True),
            pd.to_datetime(f"1/{m2}/{y2}", dayfirst=True),
        )
    )
    cur1 += ofs1
    cur2 = cur1 + ofs2


df = df.sort_values(by="Dates").set_index("Dates")

all_data = {}
for a, b in ranges:
    d = df[a:b].groupby("Category").quantile(0.9)
    all_data[f"{a:%b %y} - {b:%b %y}"] = d

df = (
    pd.concat(all_data)
    .reset_index(level=0)
    .pivot(columns="level_0")
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
)

df = df[all_data.keys()].reset_index()
df.index.name, df.columns.name = None, None
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Category | Jan 22 - Mar 22 | Feb 22 - Apr 22 | Mar 22 - May 22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 9.8 | 14.8 | 17.4 |
| B | 10.8 | 15.8 | 18.4 |

Comment: Thank's for your help Andrej. That was much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dtim
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': ['01/01/2022','01/01/2022','02/01/2022','02/01/2022',
                            '01/02/2022','01/02/2022','02/02/2022','02/02/2022',
                            '01/03/2022','01/03/2022','02/03/2022','02/03/2022',
                            '01/04/2022','01/04/2022','02/04/2022','02/04/2022'],
                   'Category':['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
                   'Amount':[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]})

# Format : String --> Datetime
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
# Set Dates as index
df.set_index('Dates', drop=True, inplace=True)
# Apply quantile function on 2X31D rolling window
r = (df.groupby('Category')
       .rolling('62D')
       .quantile(0.9)
       .unstack(level=1)
       .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
       )
# Format date on column
r.columns = r.columns.strftime('%b %y')
# Suppress columns duplicates keeping the last
r = r.T.groupby(level=0).last().T
# Ascending column sorting
r = r.reindex(sorted(r.columns, key=lambda r:dtim.strptime(r, '%b %y')), axis=1)
# Rename dates columns
r.columns = ['%s-%s'%(
    (dtim.strptime(dat, '%b %y') - timedelta(weeks=8)).strftime('%b %y')
    , dat) for dat in r.columns]

print(r)
```

```
          Nov 21-Jan 22  Dec 21-Feb 22  Jan 22-Mar 22  Feb 22-Apr 22
Category                                                            
A                   2.8            7.4           12.0           17.0
B                   3.8            8.4           13.0           18.0
```

**Let's check with numpy :**

For period `Jan 22-Mar 22` Amount for category A is `[1,3,6,8,11,13]`

Checking code :

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.quantile([1,3,6,8,11,13], 0.9)
12.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Laurent - this is much appreciated